# On one specific machine, after some time, new emacsclients can no longer connect to running daemon/server

Tags: emacsclient, server

A strange problem. I run Emacs across a number of machines, with more-or-less a shared configuration.

However, on one specific machine, *after some time* I am no longer able to launch new `emacsclient` frames to make a connection to the locally-running emacs daemon.  For many hours I will have no problems connecting new emacsclient to the daemon, but eventually it occurs.  I usually find this after trying open a new emacsclient in the morning.

```
$ emacsclient -c
/usr/bin/emacsclient: connect: Connection refused
/usr/bin/emacsclient: No socket or alternate editor.  Please use:

    --socket-name
    --server-file      (or environment variable EMACS_SERVER_FILE)
    --alternate-editor (or environment variable ALTERNATE_EDITOR)
```

Currently open `emacsclient` frames continue to function normally.

The opening of new `emacsclient` frames can be re-enabled by running `(server-start)`, which of course kills off all of the currently open `emacsclient` frames.

Since the system behaves normally for some time after launching `emacs --daemon` (or `emacs --fg-daemon`, as appropriate), and since none of my other systems exhibit this behaviour, I'm at a loss of how to debug this.

Comment: Possible duplicate question with a related/tangential answer (in case it's useful): https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/46411/454

Answer (score 1):

Probably running out of I/O's? lsof(8) or ulimit might provide more information

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer?